# Cannot login to League of Legends client after 8.4 update patch

Tags: league-of-legends

I cannot login into the Garena League of Legends after the 8.4 patch update.
I have tried many fixes such as port forwarding, changing ethernet cables and so on. But none of them really work. The game logs in when I connect to my cellular data with tethering. Please help me solve this issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If it works through tethering, then it's your network.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some few things you can do:

1. Repair your client (this can easily be done by pressing the little gear)
2. Reinstall League Of Legends.
3. Enter a support ticket.